# Get rid of "Waiting x ms for caller ID information before answering"

Tags: modem, drivers, tapi

I have a program that works thru tapi to access a phone line.

The program is set up to answer a call right after the caller id becomes available.

However, the modem seems to what to take a pause after the command to answer the line is sent to the modem, wanting to wait for the Caller ID to arrive, although it has already come in.

Here is an example from a windows modem log, in bold is where he modem says "Waiting x ms for caller ID information before answering."

Is there way to prevent this waiting? a registry entry, modem command etc?

Modem being used is a hiro 50113.

I have googled for this, there a limited hits.  One programmer has a product that has resolved this but doesn't explain how, as I am a competitor I doubt he will share :-).  Also a client sent me a log using that other program, but it didn't shed any additional light.

Thanks, Rob

10-12-2014 15:00:03.548 - Recv: RING

10-12-2014 15:00:03.548 - Interpreted response: Ring

10-12-2014 15:00:03.642 - Recv: DATE=

10-12-2014 15:00:03.642 - Interpreted response: DATE

10-12-2014 15:00:03.642 - Recv: 1012

10-12-2014 15:00:03.642 - Recv: TIME=

10-12-2014 15:00:03.642 - Interpreted response: TIME

10-12-2014 15:00:03.642 - Recv: 1459

10-12-2014 15:00:03.642 - Recv: NAME=

10-12-2014 15:00:03.642 - Interpreted response: NAME

10-12-2014 15:00:03.642 - Recv: O

10-12-2014 15:00:03.642 - Recv: NMBR=

10-12-2014 15:00:03.642 - Interpreted response: NMBR

10-12-2014 15:00:03.642 - Recv: 15551234567

10-12-2014 15:00:04.266 - Answering the call.

10-12-2014 15:00:04.266 - 38400,8,N,1, ctsfl=1, rtsctl=2

10-12-2014 15:00:04.266 - **Waiting 2283 ms for caller ID information before answering**.

10-12-2014 15:00:06.559 - Continuing with answering the call.

10-12-2014 15:00:06.575 - Send: at+fclass=8

10-12-2014 15:00:06.575 - Recv: OK

Comment: Have you asked the modem manufacturer?